# Conditional (ternary) operator is going directly to else option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ternary

I am trying to make a conditional to choose a link according to the type of user I get from the sessionStorage, but it always goes directly to else.
I can't find the error, and I don't know what else to try.

I´m using React, and the function Link is what I'm using as href for the

Thank you very much!

```
export default function IndexCards(props) {

let tipoUser = sessionStorage.getItem("TipoUser")
console.log(tipoUser, "Soy tipo user")

const linkPax = "https://test.com/pax_mockUp.html"
const linkRamp = "https://test.com/ramp_mockUp.html"
const linkLogin = "https://test.com/Login/"


function Link() {
    return tipoUser === 14 ? linkPax
         : tipoUser === 15 ? linkRamp
         : linkLogin
}


return (
    <Fragment>
        <a id="idRef" href={Link()}>
            <div className="div_container">
                <div className="div_container-superior">
                    <p>{props.data.Al}{props.data.FlNoOut}</p>
                    <p>{props.data.sAPT}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="div_container-inferior">
                    <div className='ckin_container_abre'>
                        <h5>ABRE CHECK-IN</h5>
                        <p>{props.data.STDOut.slice(10)}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='ckin_container_cierra'>
                        <h5>CIERRA CHECK-IN</h5>
                        <p>{props.data.STDOut.slice(10)}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </Fragment>
);
```

}

Comment: What does `tipoUser` contain and what is the type of `tipoUser`?

Comment: Chances are, `tipoUser` is returning a string, because that's what session and local storage do: they store data as strings. So your string will never be strictly equal to `14` or `15`.

Comment: If you log `tipoUser` you see what you expect?

Comment: I'd also suggest a `switch` or an `if/else` rather than a nested ternary. They're very difficult to read.

Comment: Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should, and that's the case with nested ternary operations. so you should use if/else or switch as mentioned by andy.

Comment: It works great, I´ve changed the nested ternary for an if/else as you suggested. And then parsed the variable. 
You are great guys thank you very much for the help.

¿How do I upvote you or give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let tipoUser = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("TipoUser"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because of the type of the tipoUser variable.
This will work for you

```
let tipoUser = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("TipoUser"))
```